# Font families on the iPhone

Tags: iphone

Normally in a web app i would put a font-family in the CSS something like this

" font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;"

This way i cover my bases as to whether the target browser can handle the various fonts and will fail gracefully if it is missing some.

However that are only a limited number of fonts on the iphone and presumably if you only specify one, say Helvetica, the iPhone will always have that font and use it. So i don't really need a font-family. Do I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe future iPhone OS releases might have different fonts, or there might be different fonts in different territories.

I'd at least keep the CSS generic font ‘sans-serif’ in.

Comment: Yes i suppose the idea of future proofing is good. On the same lines Apple might open the phone up to other mobile browsers

Answer (score 3):

I have always assumed that Apple limited the fonts on the iPhone based on what looked good on the small screen.
Below is a list of fonts that are available on the iPhone:

```
* American Typewriter
* American Typewriter Condensed
* Arial
* Arial Rounded MT Bold
* Courier New
* Georgia
* Helvetica
* Marker Felt
* Times New Roman
* Trebuchet MS
* Verdana
* Zapfino
```

see [What font's are available on the iPhone?](http://cocoatouchdown.blogspot.com/2010/03/what-fonts-are-available-on-iphone.html)

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all the fonts presented in your application you may use below code:

```
NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames];

for( NSString *familyName in familyNames ){
    printf( "Family: %s \n", [familyName UTF8String] );
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];
    for( NSString *fontName in fontNames ){
        printf( "\tFont: %s \n", [fontName UTF8String] );
    }
}
```

Using the above code you may retrieve all the font and font family includes attached externel fonts (custom fonts).